# Extjs 6 - Filter grid with combobox

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I want to sort my grid with a combobox, I want that when I select a value on the combobox, the content of the grid change for example by `type` can anyone help me? thanks

this a snippet of my code:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    height: 400,
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: pagingStore,
    columns: [{
            text: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name'
        }, {
            text: 'Email',
            dataIndex: 'email'
        }, {
            text: 'Phone',
            dataIndex: 'phone'
        },
        {
            text: 'Type',
            dataIndex: 'type'
        }],
    bbar: {
        xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
        store: pagingStore,
        displayInfo: true,
        items: [
            '-', {
                xtype: 'combo',
                fieldLabel: 'List account',
                labelAlign: 'right',
                store: storeCombo,
                displayField: 'name'
            }]
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: You want your grid to be sorted on type column on selection of combobox right ?

Comment: I want something like this: > https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4va_pdrT1cceHB3N2dySDBpTVE

Comment: What will happen after customer account selection.

Comment: When customer account is selected, the grid displays only all customer account.

Comment: cool, Got it. Will try to update fiddler

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    height: 400,
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: {
        fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'type'],
        data: [{
            name: 'Homer',
            email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
            phone: '111-222-333',
            type: 'Foo'
        }, {
            name: 'Marge',
            email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
            phone: '111-222-334',
            type: 'Foo'
        }, {
            name: 'Bart',
            email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
            phone: '111-222-335',
            type: 'Bar'
        }, {
            name: 'Lisa',
            email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
            phone: '111-222-336',
            type: 'Bar'
        }]
    },
    columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name'
    }, {
        text: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email'
    }, {
        text: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone'
    }, {
        text: 'Type',
        dataIndex: 'type'
    }],
    bbar: {
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items: [
            '-', {
                xtype: 'combo',
                fieldLabel: 'List account',
                labelAlign: 'right',
                forceSelection: true,
                emptyText: '-- Select --',
                store: {
                    fields: ['type'],
                    data: [{
                        type: 'Foo'
                    }, {
                        type: 'Bar'
                    }]
                },
                displayField: 'type',
                valueField: 'type',
                listeners: {
                    change: function(combo, value) {
                        var grid = this.up('grid'),
                            store = grid.getStore();

                        if (!value) {
                            store.getFilters().removeAll();
                        } else {
                            store.filter([{
                                property: 'type',
                                value: value
                            }]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1hn4